# How to stop bbcode being cut off when cutting a string size?

Tags: php, regex

Currently I am passing through text to this function to shorten it down for taglines where there is a 255 character limit:

```
function myTruncate($string, $limit, $break=".", $pad="...") 
{ 
    // return with no change if string is shorter than $limit 
    if(strlen($string) <= $limit)
    {
        return $string; 
    }

    // is $break present between $limit and the end of the string? 
    if(false !== ($breakpoint = strpos($string, $break, $limit))) 
    { 
        if($breakpoint < strlen($string) - 1) 
        { 
            $string = substr($string, 0, $breakpoint) . $pad; 
        } 
    } 
    return $string; 
}
```

The problem is it constantly cuts off bbcodes, is there a way to have it complete whatever it was cutting off if its inside any bbcode tags?

Comment: How are you rendering the shortened value?  If you are rendering it plainly (without BBcode), consider omitting BBcode from the result.

Comment: I do want some bbcode too appear though.

Answer (score 1):

Don't parse your own BBCode.  Use the `BBCode` module that comes with PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

Answer (score 0):

There's probably no easy solution to this. You'd need to check the whole input string character for character remembering every open bbcode tag in a memory-stack (= also called a Lexer). Then, if your character limit has been reached you need to append all closing bbcode tags you have stored in your stack.

Also your truncate function has the big shortcoming that it counts the bbcode tags themselfs as part of the text length. Imagine a user posting a 250 character long link via [url=http://very long link]picture[/url]. Google Images for example creates such long links.

Your best bet is to completely strip out the bbcode for these cases, unless that features  justifies 5-20 hours of programming for the solution.